# How to display the image icon instead of image name

Tags: html, vue.js

Below I have written a code for multiuploading images using vue. So I am able to upload the images fine. But i want to enhance this and the images which is uploaded by the user that has to display instead of image name. So here while we upload a image then instead of image name i want to display image icon. So how to display the image icon please let me know.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="asad">
<template >
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h2>Multiple Files</h2>
            <hr/>
            <label>Files
                <input type="file" multiple @change="handleFileUploads( $event )"/>
                <ul v-if="files.length">
                <li v-for="(name, i) in filesNames" :key="i">{{ name }}</li>
                <li>{{ files }}</li>
                </ul>
            </label>
            
            <div>
                <img v-for="image in images" :src="image" />
              </div>
            
            <br>
            <button v-on:click="submitFiles()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
</div>
</body>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#asad',
  data(){
    return {
      files: [],
      images: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filesNames() {
      const fn = []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
        fn.push(this.files.item(i).name)
      }
      return fn
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    handleFileUploads( event ){
      this.files = event.target.files;
    },

    submitFile(){
      let formData = new FormData();
      for( var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){
        let file = this.files[i];
        formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
        this.images.push(URL.createObjectURL(file));
      }

      axios.post( '/multiple-files', formData, 
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}
      ).then(function(){
        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
      })
      .catch(function(){
        console.log('FAILURE!!');
      });
    }
  }
})
  
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: the `images` array, is it an array of paths?

Comment: hi @ Amaarrockz. yes its a path

Comment: can you add that array in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate blobs on upload to display the uploaded files

```
handleFileUploads (event) {
  this.images = [...event.target.files].map(URL.createObjectURL);
}
```

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
      images: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filesNames() {
      const fn = []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
        fn.push(this.files.item(i).name)
      }
      return fn
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleFileUploads(event) {
      this.files = event.target.files;
      this.images = [...this.files].map(URL.createObjectURL);
    },

    submitFile() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        let file = this.files[i];
        formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
      }

      axios.post('/multiple-files', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        }).then(function() {
          console.log('SUCCESS!!');
        })
        .catch(function() {
          console.log('FAILURE!!');
        });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Multiple Files</h2>
  <hr/>
  <label>
    <span>Files</span>
    <input type="file" multiple @change="handleFileUploads($event)" />
    <ul v-if="files.length">
      <li v-for="(name, i) in filesNames" :key="i">{{ name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </label>
  <div>
    <img v-for="image in images" :src="image" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <button @click="submitFiles()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @shreevardhan I have tried the solution you given. but that is not working will you please check it once. I am not able to see the images

Comment: I have updated it as snippet, run and check here

Comment: hi @ Shreevardhan this solution is working excatly fine

Comment: hi @shreevardhan. I have one issue here while user select multiple images to upload. So here i am trying to add functionality to remove some images after uploading multiple images. like user will select one image and click on cross icon to remove the image. How can we achieve if u have any idea please let me know

Comment: If you could share a code snippet or a sandbox link, I can help you out.